# Codeigniter - Restrict teachers to only the subject(s) they teach

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I have a form that allows teachers send homework to their students. It is vital for each teacher to be restricted to only the classes and subjects they teach.

However, when the teacher want to submit or search for homework, they get to see all the subjects for that class. This is really problematic inn terms of privacy. There have been cases of teachers accidentally deleting the homework of other teachers.

I want to prevent all that by allowing teachers view only the subjects they teach.

[image]

***view***

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="pwd"><?php echo $this->lang->line('subject') ?></label><small class="req"> *</small>
<select class="form-control" name="modal_subject_id" id="modal_subject_id">
<option value=""><?php echo $this->lang->line('select') ?></option>

</select>
<span id="name_add_error" class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('modal_subject_id'); ?></span>
</div>
</div>
```

***I think this is the script***

```
 $(document).ready(function (e) {

        getSectionByClass("<?php echo $class_id ?>", "<?php echo $section_id ?>", 'secid');

        getSubjectGroup("<?php echo $class_id ?>", "<?php echo $section_id ?>", "<?php echo $subject_group_id ?>", 'subject_group_id')
        getsubjectBySubjectGroup("<?php echo $class_id ?>", "<?php echo $section_id ?>", "<?php echo $subject_group_id ?>", "<?php echo $subject_id ?>", 'subid');
```

modified

Teachers are linked to the subjects they teach in the subject_timetable

***subject_timetable***

```
CREATE TABLE `subject_timetable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `day` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `class_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `section_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject_group_subject_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `staff_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_from` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_to` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `room_no` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

***model***

```
 public function get($id)
    {

        $this->db->select('subject_timetable.*,subject_group_subjects.subject_id,subjects.name,subjects.code,subjects.type');
        $this->db->from('subject_timetable');
        $this->db->join('subject_group_subjects', 'subject_timetable.subject_group_subject_id = subject_group_subjects.id');
        $this->db->join('staff', 'staff.id = subject_timetable.staff_id');
        $this->db->join('subjects', 'subjects.id = subject_group_subjects.subject_id');
        $this->db->where('subject_timetable.id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->row();
    }
```

Comment: share the related table details and code where you query the db

Comment: at least let us see homework table

Comment: modified the post

Comment: store the classes and subject teachers teach in `session` or get that data when on this `URL`, then show the query the data with those `class id` and `subject id`, using `ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to make ajax call after every select option is selected with the selected value as your condition.